# mat Dialog: How to create 2 custom dialogs with different styles

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, mat-dialog

I have 2 components (1 dialog per component), and i want to have an dialog with opacity: 0, and another dialog with opacity: 1.
I used this:

```
::ng-deep {
  .cdk-overlay-backdrop.cdk-overlay-backdrop-showing {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

but it also affects the other mat dialog. What can I do?

Comment: using ng-deep can make your styling to apply on multiple (unwanted) targets. 
Can you show your html for both dialogs?

Comment: I can't, sorry.

Comment: Are u creating those dialogs through typescript or static html?

Comment: with typescript.

Comment: hmm, i solved :). I used: backdropClass: 'tt'

Comment: But i don't know why works :)).

Comment: ahuahuah I could answer either cause I didn't saw the code. But glad you solved! o/

Answer (score 1):

As you open a dialog using the open method, you can add configuration to the dialog you want to have. You can see all the available `MatDialogConfig` properties here  - https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api.

In this case, you can create your custom backdrop class by adding it to the config.

```js
let dialogRef1 = dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, {
  backdropClass: 'backdrop-class-name-1'
});
```

Then you can use ng-deep to add the stylings that you want.

```css
::ng-deep {
  .cdk-overlay-backdrop.cdk-overlay-backdrop-showing {
    .backdrop-class-name-1 {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Then for the other dialog, you just need to change the  name of the backdropClass.

```js
let dialogRef2 = dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, {
  backdropClass: 'backdrop-class-name-2'
});
```

Then apply the styles

```css
::ng-deep {
  .cdk-overlay-backdrop.cdk-overlay-backdrop-showing {
    .backdrop-class-name-2 {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
}
```

In this way, the two dialogs won't affect each other using `ng-deep`.